# How to create a datalab Linux instance that runs ubuntu OS?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I want to create a Datalab Linux instance that runs Ubuntu OS. I tried this command:

`datalab create [Instance-Name] --image-name ubuntu-1604-xenial-v2xxxxx`

The instance has been created. However, I can't access the Datalab notebooks via http://localhost:8081/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Datalab image is based on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/master/containers/base/Dockerfile#L15). Is there a specific feature you're looking fore?
As for the `datalab create` command, it expects a Datalab Docker image in order to be able to run Datalab at port 8081.

EDIT

Here are the steps to install `pyodbc` that worked for me:

```
!apt-get update
!apt install -y python3-pip   # if you need this for python 3
!apt install -y unixodbc-dev
!pip install pyodbc           # or !pip3 if you need this for python 3
```

Then you can do `import pyodbc` in a cell. You might need to reset the session to get a new kernel that can pick up the pip install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm trying to install pyodbc on datalab notebook. I followed the instructions to install pyodbc in this doc https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install but it doesn't work for some reason. The error message is :   Failed building wheel for pyodbc

Comment: Updated the answer to include steps for this. Please change the question title to reflect this too.

Comment: Hi! I tried both python2 and 3 and got the following error: 
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dfqoxqux/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-sku51ozu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dfqoxqux/pyodbc/